# webview content not getting updated

Tags: ios, webview

Loading content of `NSString` in `UIWebView`.
and then edit the content of nsstring in another view. once I push back to that screen the content in `NSString` get updated but the content in `UIWebView` don't get updated.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.responseMessageWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.middlecontainerScroller.frame];
        [self.middlecontainerScroller addSubview:self.responseMessageWebView];

        self.responseMessageWebView.opaque=NO;
        [self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
        self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView.delegate=self;
        self.responseMessageWebView.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.responseMessageWebView.delegate = self;
        [self.responseMessageWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        self.responseMessageWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView.bounces         = false;
        self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
        [self.responseMessageWebView reload];
    NSString* htmlHead=@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>\
                * {\
                word-wrap: break-word;\
                }\
                </style>\
                </head>\
                <body>";
                NSString* html=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Hello world my testing string%@",htmlHead,@"</body></html>"];
                [self.responseMessageWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {}
```

Once I pop back the string value is updated from  `Hello world my testing string` to  `my testing string`.

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        self.responseMessageWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.middlecontainerScroller.frame];
            [self.middlecontainerScroller addSubview:self.responseMessageWebView];

            self.responseMessageWebView.opaque=NO;
            [self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
            self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView.delegate=self;
            self.responseMessageWebView.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.responseMessageWebView.delegate = self;
            [self.responseMessageWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            self.responseMessageWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView.bounces         = false;
            self.responseMessageWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
            [self.responseMessageWebView reload];
        NSString* htmlHead=@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>\
                    * {\
                    word-wrap: break-word;\
                    }\
                    </style>\
                    </head>\
                    <body>";
                    NSString* html=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@my testing string%@",htmlHead,@"</body></html>"];
                    [self.responseMessageWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    }
        - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {}
```

I can't use `WKWebView`. is there any way to refresh the `UIWebView` ?

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that jumps out at me is that you're creating and adding your webview to its superview in `viewWillAppear:`, but probably never cleaning it up, so you're likely ending up with a duplicate one if you navigate away from that screen and coming back.

You should move all of the webview configuration code currently in `viewWillAppear:` method to somewhere like `viewDidLoad` instead. That means basically everything other than the lines where you set up the HTML string and the `loadHTMLString:` call at the end. You also shouldn't need the `reload` call, I don't think it should have any effect.

It's possible that this will fix your problem, but if not, the only other thing unaccounted for is the actual `htmlHead` property. Is that actually getting updated somewhere? If not, the problem isn't the webview anyway, since you're not updating the data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I move my web view alloc-init related code to viewdidload and yes I had make sure my html head string is getting updated. but still not able to get the updated content

Comment: did you breakpoint and check or `print` the value of `htmlHead` in `viewWillAppear` to make sure it's actually updated? Maybe you can provide the code you use to update the string.